# In Django urls. How can we make the link argument as optional .i.e. (\w+)

Tags: django

I want to make the arguments i pass through the urls as optional.

```
 url(r'^dashboard/forms/(\w+)|/create/$','dashboard_message_create'),
 url(r'^dashboard/forms/(\w+)/delete/$', 'delete'),
```

The problem with using "|" is that django cannot distinguish between the above 2 urls. 
I am new to django . So any pointers in this direction will be very useful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try associating both with the same view

```
url(r'^dashboard/forms/create/$','dashboard_message_create'),
url(r'^dashboard/forms/(\w+)/create/$','dashboard_message_create'),
```

Then, make sure `dashboard_message_create` works without the argument

```
def dashboard_message_create(request, name=None):
    # Body
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do better, using full re-superpowers (well, almost super, no lookahead in urlpatterns...):

```
url(r'^dashboard/forms/((?P<name>\w+)/)?create/$','dashboard_message_create'),
url(r'^dashboard/forms/(?P<name>\w+)/delete/$', 'delete'),
```

Add named args to your view and ignore the unnamed ones:

```
def dashboard_message_create(request, name, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

The `name` arg will be `None` when the `((?P<name>\w+)/)?` token matches the empty string.